# How to split specific pattern using regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have below string

```
Dim strTemplate as string = 
"<table>
  <tr>
       <td>Name</td>
       <td>Address</td>
       <td>City</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td>[%Name%]</td>
       <td>[%Address%]</td>
       <td>[%City%]</td>   
  </tr>
</table>"

Dim strSplits = New List(Of String)(Regex.Split(strval, "REGEXRequired"))
```

Now i want to write regex with split above string and give only pattern string `[%...%]`.

i.e. want `[%Name%]`, `[%Address%]`, `[%City%]` values in `strSplits` list.

any suggestion or help will be appreciated
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you use `Split()` for that?

```
Dim strSplits = New List(Of String)(Regex.Matches(strval, "\[%.*?%\]"))
```

is much easier, isn't it?

Comment: how can take distinct values ?

Comment: @PrakashPatani: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean matching value array contain distinct values. I had managed to do that..thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

this will get you going

```
/(\[%.*?%\])/g
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/kV2rK4